# UIScrollView within a panel not scrolling

Tags: ios, gridview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a "GridView" style table within a UIScrollview which itself is within a restricted space. I put it within a Scrollview so that the user would be able to scroll down if there are more rows than can be displayed.

My storyboard for the relevant section looks like this:

[image]

To test it I tried filling it with UILabels, with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    UILabel *cliLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, (60+(i*30)), 80, 40)];
    UILabel *cliColum2Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, (60+(i*30)), 150, 40)];
    UILabel *cliColum3Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, (60+(i*30)), 80, 40)];
    UILabel *cliColum4Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360, (60+(i*30)), 80, 40)];
    [cliLabel setText:@"Column 1"];
     [cliColum2Label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Column 2, row %d", i]];
    [cliColum3Label setText:@"Column 3"];
    [cliColum4Label setText:@"Column 4"];
    [self.cliTableScrollView addSubview:cliLabel];
    [self.cliTableScrollView addSubview:cliColum2Label];
    [self.cliTableScrollView addSubview:cliColum3Label];
    [self.cliTableScrollView addSubview:cliColum4Label];
}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

As you can see, there are more rows than can be displayed within the scroll view.

What I'd like to know is how to modify the above so that a scroll-bar appears, giving access to the out-of-bounds rows.

Comment: If you're targeting iOS 6, you should look at UICollectionView, which is a scroll view subclass to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIScrollView` doesn't know how much it has to scroll, you need to tell it by providing `contentSize`. For example, at the end of your loop:

```
self.cliTableScrollView.contentSize = CGsizeMake(self.cliTableScrollView.frame.size.width, 60 + i * 30);
```

Comment: Thank you. I added this line after the loop: `[self.cliTableScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.cliTableScrollView.frame.size.width, 60 + i * 30)];` ...  and it worked. Much appreciated.